# call function with ajax and sweet alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand how  call this function when I click on btn text. The only method that works is `(async () => {`   i have tried this `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').submit(function(e) {` but doesn't' works.

```js
(async () => {

const { value: file } = await Swal.fire({
  title: 'Select image',
  input: 'file',
  inputAttributes: {
    'accept': 'image/*',
    'aria-label': 'Upload your profile picture'
  }
})

if (file) {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Your uploaded picture',
      imageUrl: e.target.result,
      imageAlt: 'The uploaded picture'
    })
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}

})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>

<button class="form-control cal "  id="demo">
          Try me!
        </button>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There's no click handler, so I'm not sure what the point of the button is. Similarly there's no AJAX logic...?

Comment: with this script, I can open an input file modal. but works on if I put this (async () => {  on script. but if I call async the script start when i open the page, i would like that this script was opened when i click on button "Try me". if you try now my snippet now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the modal into a function and then call it whenever you want. This example shows initial and onclick call.

```js
const modal = async function () {

const { value: file } = await Swal.fire({
  title: 'Select image',
  input: 'file',
  inputAttributes: {
    'accept': 'image/*',
    'aria-label': 'Upload your profile picture'
  }
})

if (file) {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Your uploaded picture',
      imageUrl: e.target.result,
      imageAlt: 'The uploaded picture'
    })
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}

};

// initial modal call
modal();

// even modal call
$("#demo").click(modal);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>

<button class="form-control cal "  id="demo">
          Try me!
        </button>
```